# If it has the same object_id, why changing a value in a method doesn't affect the caller in Ruby?

Tags: ruby

I have this method:

```
def change_value(obj)
  puts obj.object_id #70275832194460
  obj = nil
  puts obj.object_id #8
end

obj = "hi there"
puts obj.object_id #70275832194460
change_value(obj)
puts obj.object_id #70275832194460
puts obj #still 'hi there', while I would expect nil.
```

Why if we are passing the object, and changing its value the new value doesn't get maintained outside of the method?

Comment: You cannot get `#123` for `puts obj.object_id #123` in line 4. Check again.

Comment: I just put a random number, because object_id would be different for all of us. Changed to the number I just got in the last execution.

Comment: You will get fixed value **8** for line 4

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your method is named badly. It is named `change_value`, but it doesn't actually change the value, it changes the *reference*. And since Ruby is pass-by-value, not pass-by-reference, changing the reference won't do anything to the caller. If you actually *did* change the value, you would be able to observe the difference:

```
def change_value(obj)
  puts obj.object_id #70275832194460

  obj.replace('hi back!')
  puts obj.object_id #70275832194460

  obj = nil
  puts obj.object_id #8
end

obj = 'hi there'
puts obj.object_id #70275832194460

change_value(obj)
puts obj.object_id #70275832194460

puts obj # 'hi back!'
```

Comment: That's interesting. So, if I was to pass an Integer, how would I replace it, so that the outside value also changes?

Comment: You can't. `Integer`s don't allow you to mutate them. Ruby is an object-oriented language, you can only do to an object what it allows you to do. `Integer`s don't have any methods to mutate their state, therefore you can't.

Answer (score 4):

You are not changing the value of the object. You are changing the value of a variable. While it contains the `String` object `"hi there"`, it has one value. When it contains the value `nil`, it is different (and as Nishu points out, `nil.object_id` is decidedly unrandom).

The important point is the fact that `obj` inside `change_value` is *another variable* that contains the same reference as the original `obj` that you called the function with. When you change that variable's reference, it is not reflected in the variable where you called the function. It is easier to see if you change the variable names:

```
def change_value(inner_var)
  puts inner_var.object_id # points to the same string as outer_var
  inner_var = nil
  puts inner_var.object_id # inner_var is nil now; outer_var still same
end

outer_var = "hi there"
puts outer_var.object_id # points to a string
change_value(outer_var)
puts outer_var.object_id # still points to the string
                         # (only inner_var is nil, and it doesn't exist any more)
```

Answer (score 0):

The scope of a local variable is within a method definition. Even if you changed `obj` within the method definition, that would not affect the variables outside of it. Outside of the method definition of `change_value`, the `obj` still refers to the same object as before.